# leading specialcharacters appear as trailing while using direction rtl

Tags: css, html

I am using direction property for a label. My label contains windows style directory paths(the ones with backslashes). The purpose of using `direction:rtl;` is to show the end part(or rather filenames) of the path, but the problem is I am **getting the leading backslashes as trailing** which might confuse the user. How can I prevent this.

Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pguwo67m/2/

This is what I am working on:
[image]

---

AddenduM

I have noticed that this problem also arises for other leading special characters as well.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6L1az99t/1/

Comment: `direction:rtl;` should only be used for localization.

Comment: how else do i display the end part of the directory path?

Comment: Use javascript or a server side language to alter the path.

Comment: You have a path such as `\development\application\models\cron\dropshipmodel.php` and just want to display `dropshipmodel.php` correct? In that case either the HTML needs to be altered or the text needs to be retrieved by javascript, adjusted, and then replaced.

Comment: checkout the update, is your option still feasible? I don't think, thank you for your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83537/discussion-between-jimjimmy1995-and-shekhar-joshi).

Comment: How about the bootstrap-css `.truncate-start` class, which trims characters in the front if a string gets too long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this which will remove part of the path when it is too long:

```js
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

window.onload = function () {
    adjustWidths();
};

function adjustWidths() {
  // get all label elements
  var labels = document.querySelectorAll('.path').forEach(function (lab) {
    var width = lab.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    if (width >= 260) {
      var path = lab.innerHTML;
      var pathArr = path.split("\\");
      var newpath = pathArr[0] + '\\...\\' + pathArr[pathArr.length - 1];
      lab.title = path;
      lab.innerHTML = newpath;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
input {
    width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label class="path">development\productinfo.php</label>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label class="path">development\application\models\cron\dropshipmodel.php</label>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label class="path">develoment\application\controllers\cron\dropship.php</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label class="path">development\application\models\cron\dropshipmodel.php</label>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label class="path">develoment\application\controllers\cron\dropship.php</label>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
        <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label class="path">development\productinfo.php</label>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label class="path">development\application\models\cron\dropshipmodel.php</label>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label class="path">develoment\application\controllers\cron\dropship.php</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this.

Changes -
1. Add text in span inside label 
2. Set width of span and display as block.

Thats it.

```css
label {
    direction: rtl;
    float: left;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

label span{
width:150px !important;
display:block;
    
}

input {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="checkbox">
        <label class="alterable"><span> \\\\development\productinfo.php</span></label>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label  class="alterable"><span>\development\application\models\cron\dropshipmodel.php</span></label>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label  class="alterable"><span>\develoment\application\controllers\cron\dropship.php</span></label>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
    <div>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label  class="alterable"><span>This is normal text, i want to display end part of a string</span></label>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Thnaks.

Comment: i need to display the path, and make sure the file name is visible

Comment: Check updated code snippet, You can adjust the display text and width of text to display as per your requirements.

Comment: i see backslashes in front.